# While loops drawing diamonds

Tags: java, while-loop

I'm having some issues with while loops. I've got a task to print a diamond with 2 input variables:
1) Integer to represent number of rows/max number of chars in middle
2) Char to be printed:
Psuedo code:
7 = int
$ = char
Program should print (and account for spaces on the left side):
http://pastebin.com/cspgz3bA

My while loops are a mess it seems. Right now they are printing (* simulate spaces):
http://pastebin.com/cspgz3bA

I've discovered that separating the diamond into two triangles (upper & lower) to be the easiest way of tackling this, however my code seems to be complete garbage...

EDIT:: This is for the top half of the triangle only, hence the (rows/2)+1 - it's meant to stop after finishing the middle row.

```
    rows = integerInput;
    maxSpace = integerInput;

    while (currentRow <=((rows/2)+1)) {
        spaceReq = ((maxSpace -1)/2);    // determines spaces required
            while (spaces < spaceReq) {  

                System.out.print("*");
                spaces++;
            }
            while (charPrinted < charReq){
                System.out.print(charInput);
                charPrinted++;

            }               
            currentRow++;
            maxSpace--;
            charReq = charReq +2;
            System.out.println("");
        }
```

Can someone point out why this works for the 1st iteration, but breaks on the next ones?

Thank you!

Comment: would you care to post a more complete code? inputs/outputs? Ideally, post an SSCCE http://sscce.org

Comment: Sorry, I should have done that - jpm got me the answer I was looking for without it though :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`charPrinted` and `spaces` need to be reset to `0` at the top of the outer loop.

Comment: Huzah! That did it right there. I completely forgot to reset them. You are a gentleman and a scholar :)

Comment: I'm getting this now:                                              ***x
**xxx
**xxxxx
*xxxxxxx
*xxxxxxxxx
It's not perfect, but I can tune my math a wee bit. Thanks again

Comment: Yeah, the trick there is that `maxSpace` should be calculated up front as `integerInput / 2`. No need for the minus 1, since this is integer division, and will truncate for you. Then, just use `maxSpace` instead of trying to calculate `spaceReq`. So the first, inner loop would be `while (spaces < maxSpace) {...}`, and the mutation at the end of the loop would still be `maxSpace--`.